# Which ball arrives earlier in the lower right corner?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A rectangular shaped pipe with **rounded corners** is placed in a vertical plane. Two balls are introduced in the upper left corner, if the two balls are introduced at the same times, which one arrives sooner?

[image]

My solution is: Both balls arrive at the same time because the distances, initial velocities and acceleration (gravity) are the same along both paths, but I have my doubts because of rounded corners, and maybe there is an centripetal acceleration that I'm not considering.

Comment: The times are not the same because the velocity they transverse the long paths is different. I wish you would post some the equations you have derived to back-up your claim.

Comment: Yes, I wrote my reasoning after V.F answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that there is no friction and corners have no effect on the speed.

With that out of the way, try to figure out which path would be faster, if the rectangle was almost horizontal.

Sometimes, taking things to an extreme could clarify the picture.

Comment: I think I got it, if the rectangle is almost horizontal the almost vertical path would be the faster, because that it gets faster first. I think that rounded corners makes the final speed in A be the initial speed in B. So if corners were not like that the initial speed in B will be zero and so the time will be the same to both paths

Comment: @JoséIgnacioLobato You got it.